# sping boot + JSP+JAVA web application facing tomcat service 100% consumption of CPU

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jsp, tomcat

We are having sping boot + JSP+JAVA web application on server with http://xyx,xy,x,x:8085/path/addEmployee. When all the users logged in tomcat service consumes 100% CPU and application gets down. I tried increasing max connections too in server.xml file. Even does the affinity settings wherein we increase/decrease the no. of cores. But still facing the same issue. I want to do load balancing with Nginx webserver. Can someone provide detail steps for the same?

Comment: Can you share your JVM memory configuration?

Comment: 2048M is my JVM heap memory